# adding semicolon at the end those do not have one

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I have file in which most(NOT ALL) lines ends with a semicolon. I would like to add semicolon at the end of only those line thats do not ends with a semicolon. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Technically, this will work:

```
sed '/;$/!s/$/;/' input
```

But you probably care about trailing whitespace, so:

```
sed '/; *$/!s/$/;/' input
```

If your sed supports `\s`:

```
 sed '/;\s*$/!s/$/;/' input
```

Or you might use:

```
sed '/;[[:space:]]*$/!s/$/;/' input
```

Answer (score 6):

Using sed:

```
sed -i '/[^;] *$/s/$/;/' input_file
```

which means:

```
-i          overwrite the original file with new contents
/[^;] *$/   find lines that do not contain a `;` at the end (after 
            ignoring trailing spaces)
s/$/;/      add a semicolon at the end
```

Comment: Except that `-i` does not edit the file in place, but replaces the file with a new one.  `-i` is a non-standard option that is best avoided.

Comment: I like this answer because it explains the regex. THX!